# Getting desired size of UIButton (that contains an image) in a Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

a little new to Swift but as mentioned I have Table View in which each cell contains a button (in the form of an image) but I'm having trouble getting the correct cell size. The cell's height is always way to high, here's a picture of what I'm seeing.

[image]

as you can see the button's image / cell is elongated. How can I get each cell/button to be a more appropriate size?
Here's the code where I'm creating the cells

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SportsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SportTableViewCell

    let index = mlbLogos.startIndex.advancedBy(indexPath.row)
    cell.logoButton.setImage(mlbLogos.values[index], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.logoButton.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    cell.logoButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 32,height: 32)


    return cell
}
```

EDIT: As far as storyboard constraints, I'm simply centering the UIButton in the prototype cell and expanding the button to be as large as the cell, then I just use the suggested constraints

Comment: try to add the cell height by coding or in storyboard. 
tableview.rowHeight = someInt

Comment: I've tried changing the cell's row height in storyboard but it unfortunately has zero effect

Comment: Will the size of button will change along with the Image?